# Do all web hosting services routinely allow their OSes to go well beyond EOL?

Tags: web-hosting

An organization that I volunteer for uses a web hosting service for their web page.  In doing some admin work for them, I discovered that the server hosting the site was running a rhel 6 derivative, more than two years after EOL.  They finally upgraded in the fall of 2022 but I felt that they could no longer be trusted.  I did some research to find an alternative and settled on one that had good reviews.  The organization agreed to change hosts and I started the process only to find that the alternative hosting service was even further behind and was still running a rhel 6 derivative.

In my mind, it is unconscionable for a hosting company to run these services on an OS that is more than two years out of date.  Am I living in a dream world and this the norm for the industry?

Comment: You get what you pay for. I  feel that this is really asking for reccomendations, which is off topic.

Comment: It almost seems that you want to run your own service - why not get a VPS, throw your preferred OS on it and host yourself?   While RHEL6 is very old,   I comment its also possible that the company is using RHEL ELS which has support until 30 June 2024 (https://access.redhat.com/product-life-cycles?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux).    its worth commentin that most attacks on websites come from the higher layers (ie application layer) rather then attacking the OS in ways which are materially different between older and newer OS's.

Comment: I would love to run my own VPS but this is my last year with the organization and there is no assurance that someone else with the know-how will step up to maintain it.

Comment: Do "ALL" webhosting services go beyond EOL?  Easy answer to that is NO.  Some do, but not ALL.